# Can memory mapped files created in Global space be enumerated?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, vmmap

I would like to do this:

```
var globalMemoryMappedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"Global\");
```

But in my experience it does not work.  Is there a way to enumerate memory mapped files in Global space?

I know VMMap (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx) displays memory mapped files in its "Shareable" section but I don't know how it does that.  I've looked for the VMMap code but I'm not sure it is open source.

Comment: I'm sure the answer will be posted but why do you need this?

Comment: It would help track down memory leaks in an application that uses mmfs for inter process data sharing.  VMMap shows the size of the mmfs but not the names.  With the names I could also open them and read the headers for more specific info.